# Transaction lock in sql

Tags: sql

Two processes are running simultaneously on a table. One is updating the records.  The other is reading the data. While updating it is locking the table.so I am unable to read the data. Help to to handle the same.
Thanks,
Bibhu

Comment: What database are you using? Could we see your table structures? What queries are you trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using SQL Server. You can use the WITH NOLOCK hint in your select statement, so the read goes through. However, you should be aware that it is a dirty read. Since the update statement is changing the data and the changes may or may not have been committed, the result of the read (select) statement can be problematic.

Here is a link to a page with more details and simple examples
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/